# Iteration on range elements of helm chart minus latest

Tags: arrays, kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

I would like to iterate the following array of objects put in my values.yaml file

```
elements:
 -elem1: value
  elem2: value
  elem3: value
 -elem1: value
  elem2: value
  elem3: value
```

the triplet in each - are values related to each other.
I have seen I can use **range** in something like:

```
env:
 - name: ELEMENTS
   value: "{{- range .Values.elements}}{{.elem1}}.{{.elem2}}.{{ .elem3}}             {{- end }}"
```

but this is then translated in something like :

```
env:
- name: ELEMENTS
   value: "value.value.value value.value.value"
```

Is there any way to iterate these elements minus the latest one?
I would like to map the content I am reading as json, but I have to iterate minus the latest element to put then the element in my json output.

The final output should be something like:

```
ELEMENTS="{[ "elem1":value, "elem2": value, "elem3": value],["elem1":value, "elem2": value, "elem3": value]}"
```

Comment: What is your use case? There may be something else you are looking for.

Comment: hi @ChrisBolton, the ambition is to fetch the list of values and pass them to my application.. previously I wanted to use a config map that consisted of a json file of values, I am now wondering if it is possible to do the same by using the range command, creating the env variable as a json content.